# Extract XML data from XML table column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to extract XML data from a XML column in a table so i have the data in individual columns like

| company name | system date | reference number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company 1 | 2016-01-01 | 11111 |

The table with XML has 4 columns id, file name, XMLdata and load date

It contains the XML from different XML files in the XMLdata column

Below is an example of the XML stored in the column one of the columns in a table called XMLFilesTable:

```
<Publication>
  <Addressee SubscriberReference="1" CompanyName="company 1" CompanyNumber="">
  </Addressee>
  <Content>
    <CommonExtract SystemDate="2023-01-31" SystemProcessRef="00000F75CS">
      <message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.origostandards.com/schema/soap/v1">
        <m_control>
          <control_timestamp></control_timestamp>
          <message_id></message_id>
          <message_type></message_type>
          <message_version></message_version>
          <expected_response_type></expected_response_type>
          <initiator_id></initiator_id>
          <responder_id />
        </m_control>
        <m_content xmlns="http://www.origostandards.com/schema/ReceiveRemunerationStatement/v1/LoadStatementRequest">
          <payee_firm xmlns="http://www.origostandards.com/schema/RemunerationStatement/v1">
            <company_name>company 1</company_name>
            <reference>
              <issuing_authority_name>other</issuing_authority_name>
              <type>Other</type>
              <reference_number>111111</reference_number>
            </reference>
           </payee_firm>
        </m_content>
       </message>
    </CommonExtract>
  </Content>
</Publication>
```

Below is the script i am using, it works up until i try and include the reference_number field and the MY_XML3 cross apply. After that it returns 0 rows, so not sure i understand why its now not returning any rows.

```
SELECT [Id]
       ,MY_XML.Pub.value('@CompanyName','varchar(250)')
       ,MY_XML2.Pub.value('@SystemDate','date')
       ,MY_XML3.Pub.value('@reference_number','varchar(10)')
       ,xmldata
    FROM dbo.XMLFilesTable as tbl
          CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Addressee') AS MY_XML (Pub) 
          CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Content/CommonExtract') AS MY_XML2 (Pub)
          CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Content/CommonExtract/message/m_content/payee_firm/reference') AS MY_XML3 (Pub)
```

Comment: The XML you have provided isn't valid; the `Publication` node isn't closed.

Comment: Should be there now

Comment: For the *why* you are getting no rows, this is because the `message`, `m_content` and `Payee_firm` nodes are all in a name space and you don't define it, those the nodes aren't found.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you aren't getting any rows is because you are using `CROSS APPLY`, which means that a row *must* be found for data to be returned (like an `INNER JOIN`), however no rows are found due to the some of your nodes have a namespace defined but you don't define that if your calling SQL. As a result the node `message` can't be found, as message has a namespace of `'1'`.

You need to define your namespace(s) with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` and then define those in the call. I also change the way you reference the node `message` onwards; there's no need to go from the root again, you should go from the prior `CommonExtract` node. I also give your objects *meaningful* aliases, such as `A` for `Address` and `CE` for `CommonExtract`:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<Publication>
<Addressee SubscriberReference=''PCI1'' CompanyName=''Test company'' CompanyNumber=''''>
</Addressee>
<Content>
    <CommonExtract SystemDate=''2023-01-31'' SystemProcessRef=''''>
        <message xmlns:xsi="1" xmlns:xsd="1" xmlns="1">
            <m_content xmlns="1">
                <payee_firm xmlns="1">
                    <company_name>Test company</company_name>
                    <reference>
                        <issuing_authority_name>other</issuing_authority_name>
                        <type>Other</type>
                        <reference_number>111111</reference_number>
                    </reference>
                </payee_firm>
            </m_content>
        </message>
    </CommonExtract>
</Content>
</Publication>';
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('1' AS ns,
                    '1' AS xsi,
                    '1' AS xsd)
SELECT [Id],
       P.A.value('@CompanyName', 'varchar(250)'),
       C.CE.value('@SystemDate', 'date'),
       pf.r.value('(ns:reference_number/text())[1]', 'int'),
       xmldata
FROM (VALUES (1, @XML)) tbl (Id, xmldata)
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Addressee') P(A)
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Content/CommonExtract') C(CE)
    CROSS APPLY C.CE.nodes('ns:message/ns:m_content/ns:payee_firm/ns:reference') pf(r);
```

---

It seems that the XML you supplied wasn't a good, meaningful, example. You don't have 3 name spaces all with the value `'1'`, you have 3 different name spaces. When you used the solution you didn't change the attempt for this, meaning the solutions failed. As you have 3 **different** namespaces, you need to define *all three*.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.origostandards.com/schema/soap/v1' AS ns1,
                    'http://www.origostandards.com/schema/ReceiveRemunerationStatement/v1/LoadStatementRequest' AS ns2,
                    'http://www.origostandards.com/schema/RemunerationStatement/v1' AS ns3)
SELECT [Id],
       P.A.value('@CompanyName', 'varchar(250)'),
       C.CE.value('@SystemDate', 'date'),
       pf.r.value('(ns3:reference_number/text())[1]', 'int'),
       xmldata
FROM (VALUES (1, @XML)) tbl (Id, xmldata)
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Addressee') P(A)
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Content/CommonExtract') C(CE)
    CROSS APPLY C.CE.nodes('ns1:message/ns2:m_content/ns3:payee_firm/ns3:reference') pf(r);
```

It's important you take the time to understand the solutions here; you can't just "copy pasta" a solution which uses your initial namespace of `'1'` and expect it to work for namespaces with entirely different names.

Comment: So i have tried these and also tried changing CROSS APPLY to OUTER APPLY. It is now returning rows however reference_number is still returning blank

Comment: Could just use a single namespace definition if they are all the same URI

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, @JessicaNutt , it works fine ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xp34.png) because [db<>fiddle](//dbfiddle.uk) is down). Perhaps the data you've given us and the data you have aren't representative of each other.

Comment: @JessicaNutt Works fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/186655

Comment: Sorry i had to remove sensitive info from the original XML, i might have removed too much. i have reapplied the XML in the original post which might help

Comment: I have updated the answer @JessicaNutt , however, the real problem here was the lack of meaningful sample data and your incorrect implementation of the solutions you were provided, not the solutions themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Starting from the `<message>` and down  below, all XML elements are bound to the different namespaces. Their declaration and usage were missing.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Publication>
    <Addressee SubscriberReference="1" CompanyName="company 1" CompanyNumber="">
    </Addressee>
    <Content>
        <CommonExtract SystemDate="2023-01-31" SystemProcessRef="00000F75CS">
            <message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.origostandards.com/schema/soap/v1">
                <m_control>
                    <control_timestamp></control_timestamp>
                    <message_id></message_id>
                    <message_type></message_type>
                    <message_version></message_version>
                    <expected_response_type></expected_response_type>
                    <initiator_id></initiator_id>
                    <responder_id/>
                </m_control>
                <m_content xmlns="http://www.origostandards.com/schema/ReceiveRemunerationStatement/v1/LoadStatementRequest">
                    <payee_firm xmlns="http://www.origostandards.com/schema/RemunerationStatement/v1">
                        <company_name>company 1</company_name>
                        <reference>
                            <issuing_authority_name>other</issuing_authority_name>
                            <type>Other</type>
                            <reference_number>111111</reference_number>
                        </reference>
                    </payee_firm>
                </m_content>
            </message>
        </CommonExtract>
    </Content>
</Publication>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.origostandards.com/schema/soap/v1' AS ns1
    , 'http://www.origostandards.com/schema/ReceiveRemunerationStatement/v1/LoadStatementRequest' AS ns2
    , 'http://www.origostandards.com/schema/RemunerationStatement/v1' AS ns3)
SELECT [Id]
   ,MY_XML.Pub.value('@CompanyName','varchar(250)') AS CompanyName
   ,MY_XML2.Pub.value('@SystemDate','date') AS SystemDate
   ,MY_XML3.Pub.value('(ns3:reference_number/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS reference_number
   ,xmldata
FROM @tbl as tbl
      CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Publication/Addressee') AS MY_XML(Pub) 
      CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('Publication/Content/CommonExtract') AS MY_XML2(Pub)
      OUTER APPLY MY_XML2.Pub.nodes('ns1:message/ns2:m_content/ns3:payee_firm/ns3:reference') AS MY_XML3 (Pub);
```

Comment: Provide a [mre] then, @JessicaNutt .

Comment: Also, that's my code you've copy-pasta'd there...

Comment: My answer is following a  **minimal reproducible example** paradigm. You copy it as-is to SSMS, run it, and it is working. Please see my comment how to provide it under your original question. We need all of it, i.e. ##1-4

Comment: @JessicaNutt the namespaces in your question are different to what you provided originally. I ***assume*** you did change the one's defined in `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` when you used our attempts to be representative of your *actual* namespaces, right..? As `message` , `m_content` and `payee_firm` asll  have different namespaces now, you *did* properly define **all** of those in your attempt, right..?

Comment: yes i did change them to the ones i had

Comment: When I use the appropriate namespaces, it all still works, @JessicaNutt .

Comment: I updated the answer based on the modified XML sample. Check it out.